# Error while trying to decode a json response from CURL request

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to decode a json response that looks like this and get only the value for USD

```
{"data":{"currency":"TRX","rates":{"AED":"0.22938983227","USD":"0.06245299"}}}
```

```
    $url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=TRX";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // On dev server only!

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result, true);

echo $json['USD'];
```

But I keep getting this error message - Notice: Undefined index: USD in C:\xampp\htdocs*********.php on line 19

Comment: Would `var_dump($json)` and make sure it is indexed as expected. Note the `data` key.

Comment: No, but this key exists: $json['data']['rates']['USD'];  I think what you expect the array to look like and what it really looks like are different.  Use print_r on the array to see it.  Something like: echo "<pre>"; print_r($json); echo "</pre>";

Comment: Also, try putting the json response into a json formatter like http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/ to see it easier.

Comment: `$json['data']['rates']['USD']`

Comment: @ChrisStrickland, It worked, thanks for the help, I really do appreciate it

Comment: @unknownuser You can accept Chris Strickland's answer.

Comment: Glad it helped you, it was no problem.  @WahyuKristianto I think there's a wait period before you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you expect the array to look like and what it actually looks like are different.  `$json['USD']` doesn't exist, but `$json['data']['rates']['USD']` does.

You can use `print_r` on the array to view it:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($json); echo "</pre>";
```

or you could also use a json formatter like http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/, which I personally use all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
```

to:

```
$json = json_decode($result);
```

and print you data in object oriented mode like this:

```
echo $json->data->currency . ' > '. $json->data->rates->USD;
```

I hope to be helpful